# Getting reputation back after marking down a question that was clarified afterwards

Tags: support, reputation, answers, down-votes, deleted-answers

Sorry - I haven't found any other place to put this question. But I have a question regarding reputation and deleted answers:

- One question (I can provided link) had not quite clear question about assembly. However the word assembly was not mentioned at the time anywhere (only x86) and it was marked homework and was marked by tag C.
- Seeing C tag and homework - i.e. having no idea that the question is about assembly - I answered the question.
- Afterward (after few hours) the assembly tag was added
- Then, as my question was indeed out-of-topic at this moment I was marked down -  I belive everyone in good faith but still.

I had 2 options:

- Vote for deletion of my post as it is out-of-topic
- Explian the situation and wait until unvote to delete of answer

I choose the first option as 1. I have no chance of contacting person who voted down 2. it would left a question with wrong answer 3. I heard that after deletion of post the reputation does not count.

However it seems that markdown is permanent (at least - the change is propagated slower then other changes in reputation).

1. Can I ask for clarification for the reputation and deleted answers? Maybe only positive reputation don't count any longer?
2. Is there any chance of getting reputation back. I don't have enought time to spent on stackoverflow to 'hunt' for questions so even 2 points are (or may be rather feel) valuable.

PS. I'm not quite sure how to classify this question - discussion or support. I marked as support by sorry if it is mistag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to flag the moderator and ask for a reputation recalc to get the deleted votes to not count.